# Using two sensors simultaneously (Ibeo Scala)

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, multiple

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I am trying to use two Ibeo Scala sensors at the same time.
With the help of the following packages I am able to run one sensor and visualize it in rviz.
https://github.com/astuff/ibeo_core
https://github.com/astuff/ibeo_scala

Now I would like to setup a second Scala sensor and visualize them both in rviz.
I wrote a second launch file, where I changed the IP address and the frame_id.
The problem:
When I start the second launchfile in a new terminal, the process in the first terminal (first sensor) gets aborted.

Log:

```
^[[33m[ WARN] [1546933754.809607419]: Shutdown request received.^[[0m
^[[33m[ WARN] [1546933754.809667337]: Reason given for shutdown: [new node regiregistered with same name]^[[0m
```

How can I change the second nodes name to work along the first one ?

I tried while starting the node to change the name parameter:

```
roslaunch .... __name:=testnode
```

and I tried to add a 'remap' in the Launch file

```
<remap from="ibeo_scala" to="testnode"/>
```

None of the above works, I always end up with the same error

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312163/using-two-sensors-simultaneously-(ibeo-scala)/) by [sporc](https://answers.ros.org/users/39125/sporc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-01-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to have a unique name in the `node` part of all of your nodes, or put your nodes in a namespace.

You can see what your nodes are named with the command `rosnode list`

So either change the `name` of your nodes to something like this(add arguments for the second sensor if you want or hard code the correct values):

just to be clear, edit the name:  'node pkg="ibeo_scala" type="ibeo_scala" **name="ibeo_scala"**'

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <arg name="frame_id" default="ibeo_scala0" />
  <arg name="ip_address" default="10.152.42.111" />
  <arg name="port" default="12004" />
  <arg name="is_fusion" default="false" />
  <arg name="publish_raw_data" default="false" />

  <node pkg="ibeo_scala" type="ibeo_scala" name="ibeo_scala0">
    <param name="sensor_frame_id" value="$(arg frame_id)" />
    <param name="ip_address" value="$(arg ip_address)" />
    <param name="port" value="$(arg port)" />
    <param name="is_fusion" value="$(arg is_fusion)" />
    <param name="publish_raw_data" value="$(arg publish_raw_data)" />
  </node>

  <node pkg="ibeo_scala" type="ibeo_scala" name="ibeo_scala1">
    <param name="sensor_frame_id" value="ibeo_scala1" />
    <param name="ip_address" value="10.152.42.112" />
    <param name="port" value="12005" />
    <param name="is_fusion" value="$(arg is_fusion)" />
    <param name="publish_raw_data" value="$(arg publish_raw_data)" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

`rosnode list` would output something like

```
/rosout
/ibeo_scala0
/ibeo_scala1
```

You could also add a namespace to the node, so the relevant lines would be something like

```
....
<node ns="sensor0" pkg="ibeo_scala" type="ibeo_scala" name="ibeo_scala">
....
</node>
<node ns="sensor1" pkg="ibeo_scala" type="ibeo_scala" name="ibeo_scala">
....
</node>
```

`rosnode list` output in this case would be something like

```
/rosout
/sensor0/ibeo_scala
/sensor1/ibeo_scala
```

**After getting the nodes running in either way you will also need to configure rviz to use the correct names**

---

Regarding both nodes publishing to the same topic:

If you ran the nodes with different names instead of namespaces then this is expected and you would need to add [remaps](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap) to the node. Something like:

```
....
<node ns="sensor0" pkg="ibeo_scala" type="ibeo_scala" name="ibeo_scala">
<remap from="as_tx/point_cloud" to="as_tx0/point_cloud"/>
....
</node>
<node ns="sensor1" pkg="ibeo_scala" type="ibeo_scala" name="ibeo_scala">
<remap from="as_tx/point_cloud" to="as_tx1/point_cloud"/>
....
</node>
```

if you run the nodes in different namespaces and the node is coded sensibly you shouldn't need to remap them, the topics should appear in the namespaces like

```
/sensor0/as_tx/point_cloud
/sensor1/as_tx/point_cloud
```

If they don't appear in the namespace you would need to change the code of the node or add remaps.

---

Originally posted by [Reamees](https://answers.ros.org/users/36207/reamees/) with karma: 591 on 2019-01-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sporc](https://answers.ros.org/users/39125/sporc/) on 2019-01-08**:
Thank you. It works. I can run now two sensors simultaneously, but they are both on the same topic: "as_tx/point_cloud". When I select this topic in rviz I can see both data. Is it possible to publish each sensor to a unique topic?